# ¿Como pongo de forma descendente estos numeros?

Tags: java, eclipse, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles

Buenos días tengo este problema de codeforces:
el problema es asi: Imprime las denominaciones de todas las monedas en orden decreciente. El número de monedas debe ser el mayor posible (con la denominación dada n de la moneda más cara). Además, la denominación de cada moneda debe ser divisible por la denominación de cualquier moneda más barata. Naturalmente, las denominaciones de todas las monedas deberían ser diferentes. Si hay varias soluciones a ese problema, imprima cualquiera de ellas.

https://codeforces.com/contest/58/problem/B y primero no se como poner los numero de forma descendente y segundo creo que mi programa esta mal hecho o no se que debo corregir pero al ingresar 10 me da  1 2 5 10 y debería mostrar 10 5 1 tengo esos problemas, si me ayudarían estaría genial gracias

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Coins {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int numero;
    do{
    numero = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }while(numero<=0);
    int d = numero/2;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= d; i++) {
        if (numero%i == 0) {
            System.out.print( i + " " );  
        }
    }
    System.out.print(numero);
  }  
 }
```

[image: Imagen aqui]

Comment: Explica de que trata el problema al que tienes que dar solucion

Comment: Imprime las denominaciones de todas las monedas en orden decreciente. El número de monedas debe ser el mayor posible (con la denominación dada n de la moneda más cara). Además, la denominación de cada moneda debe ser divisible por la denominación de cualquier moneda más barata. Naturalmente, las denominaciones de todas las monedas deberían ser diferentes. Si hay varias soluciones a ese problema, imprima cualquiera de ellas.

Comment: A ver para entenderte un poco más explica cómo sería el proceso con una moneda de denominación 20 paso a paso por favor

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería quedar de la siguiente forma, lo único que necesitabas era recorrer el for de forma regresiva.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int numero;
    do {
    numero = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } while(numero <= 0);
    for (int i = numero ; i > 0; i--) {
        if (numero%i == 0) {
            System.out.print( i + " " );  
        }
    }
  }  
 }
```

Aunque basándome en el enlace que mandaste el código realmente debería quedar de la siguiente forma.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int numero;
    do {
    numero = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } while(numero <= 0);
    
    System.out.print(numero + " ");
    while (numero > 1) {
      if (numero % 2 == 0) {
        numero = numero / 2;
        System.out.print(numero + " ");
      } else {
        numero = 1;
        System.out.print(1);
      }
    }
  }  
 }
```

Explicacion:

> Si el número tiene una mitad imprimes la mitad, y el número se convierte en su mitad.
> Si el número no tiene mitad entonces imprimes 1, y el número se vuelve 1.
> Dejas de imprimir números mientras el número no llegue a 1, el cuál es el último número que se puede imprimir.